# Webfont loading cross browser differently (mac firefox issue)

Tags: css, fonts, cross-browser, rendering, webfonts

I use google "Comfortaa" font for a blog with this code

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Comfortaa&subset=greek,latin' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

However, the font (along with other fonts) are displayed more boldly on mac Firefox (display fine on Chrome mac/win firefox win etc)

I changed all em to px just to be sure, plus I though I could try font squirrel with the code

```
/* Generated by Font Squirrel (http://www.fontsquirrel.com) on November 2, 2012 */



@font-face {
    font-family: 'comfortaabold';
    src: url('comfortaa-bold-webfont.eot');
    src: url('comfortaa-bold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('comfortaa-bold-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('comfortaa-bold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('comfortaa-bold-webfont.svg#comfortaabold') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}




@font-face {
    font-family: 'comfortaalight';
    src: url('comfortaa-light-webfont.eot');
    src: url('comfortaa-light-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('comfortaa-light-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('comfortaa-light-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('comfortaa-light-webfont.svg#comfortaalight') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}




@font-face {
    font-family: 'comfortaaregular';
    src: url('comfortaa-regular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('comfortaa-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('comfortaa-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('comfortaa-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('comfortaa-regular-webfont.svg#comfortaaregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
```

Still the issue persists.(I 'm not really sure where to put the  @font face -I applied it through blogger css)

Am I doing something wrong, or is this plainly a browser rendering issue that can't be fixed?

Comment: Some browsers apply anti-aliasing to text. I don't believe this can be controlled, but I could be wrong.

Comment: If it's a google font, go to the page for that font in google, and test that page. If you see the same issue in Firefox for mac. Then at least you'll know if the issue is with the font, or your code.

Comment: Hi, I already did, and I knew it was the font, however I thought it might be fixable,and I was wondering maybe what I did was lacking something in the process. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Try using a numerical font-weight value. In the Google webfont listening you can see the correct font-weight for each style. In the case of Comfortaa these are: {font-weight: 300;} for book, {font-weight: 400;} for normal and {font-weight: 700;} for bold.